# How to retrieve data on specific date in Android database

Tags: android, date

I have a column in database that stores the date in the format(yyyy-MM-dd).I don't know where is the error in my code but it does nothing (even though the file exists) when I run the program.What should be the sql statement to retrieve data from database on specific date?Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

```
    public ArrayList<Filenames> GetByDate(String dates) {
    try {
        filename_list.clear();
        String q="SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_FILENAMES + " WHERE date=" + dates;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           Filenames contact = new Filenames();
           contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
           contact.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
           contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
           filename_list.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return filename_list;
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Does it return empty ArrayList? Can you access ANY data in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like that.

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FILENAMES + "  WHERE date = '" + dates + "'";
```

I hope this will help you...!